# New to Ipad, familiar with SQL, how to get started

Tags: sql, ipad, sqlite

I have been a SQL writer using MS Access some years ago and have been given an IPad upon my retirement. I want to create simple database driven apps using SQL. I have downloaded SQL Lite editor from the Apps Store but it seems to have a big chunk of something missing.
Question. Do I need to have an Apple computer as a workstation and then copy to the iPad, or can I use my Windows 7 PC as the authoring tool.

Where do I find the tools for creating the graphics to enhance database search results?

Do I need to use C or C++ to create the application, as I never got around to learning it.

Odd questions I know, but google searches seem to leave me totally in the dark on this topic, yet I geel that most app's seem to revolve around some database manipulation. Would be helpful if I could find a series fo links somehwere.

best regards

Kaela

Comment: Do you have programming background?

Answer (score 2):

Hi
In order to develop native applications to ios devices you need the XCode environment and knowledge in  objective c, its a bit odd and there are examples.
for that you will need a mac or run the mac os on a virtual box.
You can also create a non native app such as webapp using HTML5 and js and then import it to the XCode using Phonegap.
By using this method you will be able to create apps for many devices such as android and more and all you will have to do is to import your HTML5 and js into the supporting environment.
Just to warn you about these kind of apps, app store allows only native apps and its better to make native app because it will pass every inspection they make.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

yes, to develop on Apple's engine, you have to had an Apple computer. However, you can mount a virtual machine running OS X, but it's illegal and very complicated (but doable).

The "bible" for mac developers is here : http://developer.apple.com/.

It's recommanded to write your application in Objective C.